# How to produce a "securely random" string token in Haskell?

Tags: security, haskell, random, cryptography

I want to produce string tokens to implement the password reset functionality of a web app. They can be [v4 UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29) but it is not required.

I want each token to be "securely random" in the sense of [this SO question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93902/is-postgress-uuid-generate-v4-securely-random). The system's entropy pool should be sampled for each generated token.

I found the [*uuid*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uuid-1.3.12/docs/Data-UUID-V4.html) package, that generates v4 UUIDs. The docs mention that

> we use the System.Random StdGen as our random source.

but it is unclear to me if this is enough.

Is there other library that I should use instead?

Comment: If you look at the source code for `nextRandom` (click `Source` at the right) you'll see that it just calls `Crypto.Random.Entropy.getEntropy` for every number and according to the [documentation for `Crypto.Random`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/crypto-api-0.13.2/docs/Crypto-Random.html) "This module is for instantiating cryptographicly strong determinitic random bit generators " so I believe you should be safe.

Comment: If you are storing in the DB and using a library like persistent, then you can do it via the internal postgres method itself.

Comment: @Sibi I'm using MySQL, whose UUID function is not "securely random", judging from the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement that the system entropy pool should be sampled on each generated token sounds suspicious. Entropy is usually a scarce resource.

Let's agree that `/dev/random` is definitely out. Other processes may need it, it could lead to potential denial of service etc. First and foremost though, `/dev/random` *blocks* on read when it deems the entropy pool insufficient so it's a definite no. `/dev/urandom` on the other hand should be perfectly fine. Some say that it has issues in some odd cases (for example right after boot on diskless machines) but let's no go there.

Note that on most systems `/dev/[u]random` both use the same algorithm. The difference is that `/dev/urandom` never blocks but also not necessarily uses any new entropy on each read. So if using `/dev/urandom` counts as "sampling the system entropy pool" then whatever solution you have that properly uses it is probably fine.

However, it comes at a cost of impurity. Reading from `/dev/urandom` forces us into `IO`. Being haskellers we have to at least consider alternatives and we are in luck if only we drop the entropy-sample requirement which seems weird to begin with.

Instead we can use a crypto-secure deterministic RNG and only seed it from `/dev/random`. [`ChaChaDRG`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite-0.20/docs/Crypto-Random.html) from cryptonite which is an implementation of DJB's [ChaCha](https://cr.yp.to/chacha.html) would be a good choice. Since it is deterministic we only need `IO` to get the initial seed. Everything after that is pure.

Cryptonite offers [`getRandomBytes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite-0.20/docs/Crypto-Random.html#v:getRandomBytes) so you can tweak the length of the token to suit your needs.

Comment: "The requirement that the system entropy pool should be sampled on each generated token sounds suspicious" I agree. The problem is that I'm trying to implement a typeclass interface that leaves no room for maintaining state, unless I attempt some `unsafePerformIO` trick to initialize a global ref...

Comment: Hmm... a deterministic RNG *does* need to have it's state stored *somewhere*. If we don't allow that and we do not want explicit `IO` then your only option may indeed be reading `/dev/urandom` through `unsafePerformIO`. Seems like a last resort though.

Comment: I can perform explicit `IO`, but then either I'll have to sample `/dev/urandom` each time or use 'unsafePerformIO` to track global state.